# How in depth should javadoc explanations of how algorithms work be?

Tags: java, comments, javadoc

How in depth should I describe how an algorithm works?

For example, I'm working on a simple tetris game, and I want to explain how I rotate the [tetrominoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) in a way that the explanation doesn't cover a 100 lines, but the reader fully understands what I'm doing.

My javadoc for the algorithm as it is now:

```
/**
 * Rotates the tetromino 90 degrees clockwise.
 * <p>
 * The rotating algorithm guarantees O(n^2) time complexity and O(1) space
 * complexity, n being the width/height of the tetromino's layout.
 * <p>
 * The algorithm works by rotating each layer of the layout. A layer is
 * rotated by choosing 4 elements, one from each of the layout's sides, and
 * swapping them with each other in a clockwise manner. See an illustration
 * with the I-tetromino below:
 * <p>
 * <pre>
 * Layout:
 * 
 *     . . 1 .
 *     . . 1 .
 *     . . 1 .
 *     . . 1 .
 * 
 * Its first and second layer (layers 0 and 1):
 * 
 *   0:  x x x x   1:  . . . .
 *       x . . x       . x x .
 *       x . . x       . x x .
 *       x x x x       . . . .
 * 
 * First we swap the first layer's elements, 4 at a time:
 * 
 *   layout now:    swap these elements:
 * 
 *   . . 1 .        x . 1 x
 *   . . 1 .        . . 1 .
 *   . . 1 .        . . 1 .
 *   . . 1 .        x . 1 x
 * 
 *   layout now:    swap these elements:
 * 
 *   . . 1 .        . x 1 .
 *   . . 1 .        . . 1 x
 *   . . 1 .        x . 1 .
 *   . . 1 .        . . x .
 * 
 *   layout now:    swap these elements:
 * 
 *   . . 1 .        . . x .
 *   . . 1 .        x . 1 .
 *   1 . 1 .        . . 1 x
 *   . . . .        . x . .
 * 
 * Then we swap the second layer's elements:
 * 
 *   layout now:    swap these elements:
 * 
 *   . . . .        . . . .
 *   . . 1 .        . x x .
 *   1 . 1 1        1 x x 1
 *   . . . .        . . . .
 * 
 *   layout now:
 * 
 *   . . . .
 *   . . . .
 *   1 1 1 1
 *   . . . .
 * 
 * The tetromino is now rotated.
 * </pre>
 */
```

Should I simply omit the step-by-step illustration, prefering the readability of the rest of the class, should I ignore this issue, prefering the reader, or should I give a link to an external source where a similar algorithm is already explained in depth, possibly resulting in a dead link later? Or something else?

Comment: Is this the javadoc for a method? I prefer just writing what the method does rather than how it does it. That way you don't have to change the javadoc everytime you improve your algorithm.

Comment: I agree. I think it's reasonable to include a before and after diagram for the I tetromino, but to include all the the intermediate stages seems like overkill.

Comment: @kinbiko Yes it is. I see your point.

Comment: Yes and people should be able to understand the algorithm without comments (if your code is enough clear). You can always comment difficult parts in the code itself if required.

Comment: @ZouZou The algorithm is simple, but the code is not. I use adequately verbose variable names, but describing the work is still rather difficult. You can see the actual algorithm [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/11/07/how-to-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array-by-90-degrees-clockwise-or-counter-clockwise-like-knightfall-game/). See the `rotateClockwise` method.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Hmm, I see what you mean. It's purely algorithmic. If you're using adequate variable names like row/column etc, it should be enough clear (I hope).

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Or you could drop a web link to the actual algorithm on the javadoc.

Comment: @ZouZou I am doing that, but it's still hard to look at. A little background: I'm programming a tetris game as a school project assignment. We are supposed to follow every possible clean-code principle that is reasonable to be followed, because periodically other students will review the works of other students. I think I'm a bit ahead of the rest of the class; most of them have programmed for 2 months and are probably not very used to looking at code such as in this method of mine. I want to be a lad and even give them a chance :D

Comment: @ZouZou Yes, that had crossed my mind, but I'm afraid that at some point the link might go dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest limiting the javadoc to **what** a method does, rather than **how** it does it. This saves you from updating your JavaDocs every time you change your code. In your case, I'd be happy with writing:

```
/**
 * Rotates the tetromino 90 degrees clockwise.
 * <p>
 * The rotating algorithm guarantees O(n^2) time complexity and O(1) space
 * complexity, n being the width/height of the tetromino's layout.
 * <p>
 * @param, @return, @throws etc goes here.
 */
```

You'll have to update your JavaDocs if you improve your algorithm of course - but I'd leave it in as the complexity is something another reader (or future you) would like to know.

For the purpose of making it easy for a reviewer to understand your code I would suggest explaining the more difficult bits of the algorithm in the actual method, rather than as a javadoc. There are (at least) three good reasons for this:

1. Distance from actual code to comment is shorter, and you can spread the comments out more.
2. JavaDocs are often used by IDEs to get a quick overview of what a method/class does, putting the whole explanation of the code in the JavaDoc defeats this purpose.
3. Perhaps not applicable in your situation, but perhaps good to keep in mind, is that JavaDocs are often published when publishing something like an API. You need not publish the source code, but the JavaDocs are almost always included, and often published on the web as well. If you have an algorithm in your code that does something amazing, that you want to keep secret for business purposes, it would really defeat the purpose of explaining the algorithm in the JavaDoc. ;-)